# print label multiple times based on value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

for example if label count is 3 in database, the label should be printed 3 times in the report.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to do this in Crystal, do it on the back end (or an intermediate back end if you can't modify the one you have).

Explode each row with its label count into the number of rows you want in a temp table, or something, then build the report off that datasource.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must not use label . use Row , Datagridrow to show ur data in crystal report .

```
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgvDefaultItem.Rows
    dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("count").Value)

Next
```